# SqlAlchemy puts square brackets on sql server 2014 table name

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I'm trying to use SqlAlchemy with PyOdbc using the Microsoft ODBC Driver for Linux, but when I use the `session.query()` function, I get the following error:

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'TableName'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW)")

So I saw that the query created by orm had square brackets on `TableName`.

```
SELECT 
    [mb.Tecnico].cod_tecnico AS [mb.Tecnico_cod_tecnico], 
    [mb.Tecnico].nome AS [mb.Tecnico_nome], 
    [mb.Tecnico].login AS [mb.Tecnico_login], 
    [mb.Tecnico].senha AS [mb.Tecnico_senha] 
FROM 
    [mb.Tecnico] 
ORDER BY 
    [mb.Tecnico].nome
```

Comment: Can you show the raw query?

Comment: Is your table called actually named `TableName`?

Comment: [SQL: 'SELECT [mb.Tecnico].cod_tecnico AS [mb.Tecnico_cod_tecnico], [mb.Tecnico].nome AS [mb.Tecnico_nome], [mb.Tecnico].login AS [mb.Tecnico_login], [mb.Tecnico].senha AS [mb.Tecnico_senha] \nFROM [mb.Tecnico] ORDER BY [mb.Tecnico].nome']

Comment: Is the table actually named `mb.Tecnico` and is that the value of TableName in your error message?

Comment: The table name is 'mb.Tecnico', and its columns is cod_tecnico, nome, login and senha

Comment: The error is exactly pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'mb.Tecnico'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Comment: The SQL is correctly formed (the square brackets are needed to escape the table name because it contains a `.`).  The error either means you are connected to the wrong database or the table is bound to a schema that you are not specifying.

Comment: That's Right. So a must specify the table name and the table schema separatly.   __tablename__ = 'Tecnico'
    __table_args__ = {"schema": 'mb'}. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When the names of identifiers do not comply with the rules for regular identifiers, they must be delimited by double quotation marks or brackets.

Under "Rules for Regular Identifiers" on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx)

> 4. Embedded spaces or special characters are not allowed.